# instrument cluster warning lights

Tags: ford, warning-light, fusion

my car...UK FORD FUSION 1.6 AUTO.2006.
  ABS, BRAKE SYSTEM, ENGINE MANAGEMENT warning lights are on, the speedometer is not working and the oddometer is showing dashes.
Initial checks I have made, including abs sensor checks, fuses, brake fluid level etc, have  been ok.  My research into this problem has highlighted the fact that instrument cluster and  abs module failures are common on ford focus and fusion models. The general opinion seems to be don't go to a ford main dealer to sort the problem out. I have heard of cases where parts have been changed and the fault remains  and customers still expected to pay the bill for the work carried out!
So, instrument cluster or abs module? how can I be sure. 
I have arranged for a diagnostic check to be carried but I have been advised  it might not highlight which component is faulty.
Any advice much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't read the error codes from the ECUs then that should be your first step.  You can buy OBD2 readers for just a few pounds that can connect to your smartphone or a computer.  If you have got the codes, then update our question with them, they will help a lot.

Comment: You can goto an auto parts store and have them scan your car for free.  They do this so they can sell you parts.  Have them do a scan of your codes and populate your question.  If you can get those someone should be able to give you some ideas of the the root issues is.

Comment: Did you get a scan done?

Comment: Scan was done but unfortunately no facility  available for code printout.   Scan indicated 'abs control module not communicating with ecu'. Can I safely assume the module is faulty or should I get a  printout of error codes which may highlight other faults causing  the module communication problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have now purchased a code reader. The error code U0121 together with the message 'lost communication with anti lock braking system control module' is displayed. The diagnostic  menu gives various options for tests including live data display with the engine running ...is there anything I should be looking for that could highlight further relevant information? I have checked fuses  5  6  7  (ABS)